# JMeter Groovy Set a variable for each sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter, assertion

Is there a possibility to have variables that depend on the listener where there lay in?
So I want to execute two samplers which are working with a JSR223 Assertion. I use a groovy code which asks for the value of the variable "name". If I execute Sampler A it should say "Tom" and if i execute Sampler B it should say "Paul".
It has to be possible to execute both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You have `sampler` shorthand in the JSR223 Assertion which stands for this or that Sampler. So you can check its name by calling `sampler.getName()` function which will basically execute underlying [AbstractTestElement.getName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/AbstractTestElement.html#getName--) method. The relevant code would look like:

```
if (sampler.getName().equals('Sampler A')) {
   log.info('Tom')   
}
else if (sampler.getName().equals('Sampler B')) {
    log.info('Paul')
}
```

You can set a JMeter Variable from Groovy code using `vars` shorthand which in its turn stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

```
vars.put('foo', 'bar')
```

Once done you will be able to refer created variable as `${foo}` where required - it will have the value of `bar`

Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more details.